# Почему нельзя получить адрес указателя this?

Tags: c++, классы

Почему нельзя получить адрес указателя this?

```
class Hu {
public:
    void ps() {
        
    }
};

int main()
{
    Hu s;
    s.ps();
}
```

Компилятор неявно передаёт адрес объекта, который вызывает метод следующим образом:

```
ps(&s)
```

Почему я не могу получить адрес указателя?

```
class Hu {
public:
    Hu** ps() {
      return &this;
    }
};
```

Comment: неявная передача **this** не *обязывает* хранить этот указатель в памяти.

Comment: было бы любопытно смотреть на программу, где каждый объект заранее знает свое место в памяти и даже может разрешить изменить  его извне...

Comment: возвращайте new Hu*(this)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Значение указателя **this** имеет категорию **prvalue** и у неё нельзя получить адрес.

стандарт :

> If a declaration declares a member function or member function template of a class X, the expression **this** is a **prvalue** of type “pointer to cv-qualifier-seq X” between the optional cv-qualifier-seq and the end of the function-definition, member-declarator , or declarator .

ссылка на категории :

[Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

При выполнении метода класса, автоматически **не** создаётся место в памяти для этого указателя, а передаётся адрес любым способом на усмотрение компилятора.
Этот указатель имеет ту-же категорию, как например и `& var`, у которого тоже нельзя получить адрес : `& & var` - ошибка.